# ReactJS, TypeScript - ошибка при передаче стейта в провайдер

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Ошибка при передаче стейта в value провайдера (подсвечивается "state") `<AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>`

Не могу разобраться как исправить, помогите(

Сама ошибка

> Type '{ state: any; dispatch: React.Dispatch; }' is not
> assignable to type '{ todos: { title: string; }[]; }'.   Object
> literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist
> in type '{ todos: { title: string; }[]; }'.ts(2322) index.d.ts(325,
> 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared
> here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<{ todos: { title:
> string; }[]; }>'

```
import React, { useContext, useReducer, useState, createContext } from 'react'

const defaultState = {
  todos: []
}

const AppContext = createContext(defaultState)
const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO', DELETE_TODO = 'DELETE_TODO'

const reducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
  const { type, payload } = action
  switch (type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return { todos: [payload, ...state.todos] }
    case DELETE_TODO:
      return { todos: state.todos.filter((todo: any) => todo.id !== payload) }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const TodoForm = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const { dispatch }: any = useContext(AppContext)

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }: any) => {
    setTitle(value)
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    setTitle('')
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_TODO,
      payload: {
        id: crypto.randomUUID(),
        title
      }
    })
  }

  const handleEnter = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      handleClick();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder='enter title'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={title}
        onKeyDown={handleEnter}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const TodoList = () => {
  const { state: { todos }, dispatch }: any = useContext(AppContext)

  const handleDeletet = (id: any) => () => {
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_TODO,
      payload: id
    })
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((todo: any) => (
        <li key={todo.id}>
          {todo.title}
          <button onClick={handleDeletet(todo.id)}>X</button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultState)

  return (
    <div>
      <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
        <TodoForm />
        <TodoList />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </div>)
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум, вместо

```
const AppContext = createContext(defaultState)
```

нужно написать:

```
const AppContext = createContext({
  state: defaultState,
  dispatch: () => null
});
```

Comment: Уже лучше, теперь только на диспатч ругается 

(property) dispatch: () => null
Type 'Dispatch<any>' is not assignable to type '() => null'.ts(2322)
app.tsx(9, 3): The expected type comes from property 'dispatch' which is declared here on type '{ state: { todos: never[]; }; dispatch: () => null; }
'

Answer (score 1):

Помогло добавление интерфейса для контекста

```
interface AppContextIntreface {
  state: any,
  dispatch: any
}

const AppContext = createContext<AppContextIntreface>({
  state: defaultState,
  dispatch: () => null
})
```